# Oscilloscope showing bars above and below actual voltage. Is it broken?

Tags: oscilloscope

EDIT: performing a factory reset caused the problem to go away.

Whenever I measure a voltage on my oscilloscope, I see two bars around where the actual voltage should be. This happens on any of the 4-channels and with any of my 4 probes so it seems to be a scope issue. I'm not very experienced with oscilloscopes so I don't know if this scope is bad or if it's a setting.

In the image the probe is reading a 5V signal from a bench-top power supply, and the position on the scope has been adjusted such that I should be seeing a line in the middle of the screen. Instead I see the yellow bars above and below the actual voltage.

Does this look like a bad scope?

EDIT: I've added another photo. The first photo is on channel 1 with a 5V source. The second photo is on channel 2 with a different probe hooked up to the calibration posts on the scope.

[image: Display of 5V source, channel 1, probe 1]
[image: Display of calibration posts on scope, channel 2, probe 2]

Comment: It might be in peak detect mode, press “acquire” then choose “mode” and get it to “normal”. This is detailed better on page 4-2 of the manual: https://www.batronix.com/pdf/Rigol/UserGuide/MSO1000Z_DS1000Z_UserGuide_EN.pdf

Comment: Could be a broken scope, could be setup error, could be an error in measurement technique.  Make sure you're actually using the ground lead.  Does it increase when you increase the scope gain?  Can you turn the speed way up and trigger on a waveform?

Comment: Looks like it is just [free running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOibS.png) to me. But I also collect bad oscilloscopes. ;) So I'll give it a good home if you feel it's not working right. :)

Comment: I've added a second photo of the display when a different probe on a different channel is hooked up to the calibration posts on the scope. @Bryan Thank you for the suggestion. I took a look and the acquire mode is Normal.

Comment: Go way over to the right of the screen where there is the triggering section and press the MODE button there. You should see some changes take place on the right side of the scope screen, showing a different menu there. Let us see what that menu looks like.

Comment: @jonk I changed photo 2 to zoom out.

Comment: @TimWescott The ground lead is connected correctly. I'm triggering on channel 2 in the 2nd photo and you can see the same display problems. Different probe different channel.

Comment: @par When you adjust the triggering level, where does it draw the line at for channel 2?  (Don't want to talk about the yellow one yet.) I'm assuming you are hooking up to the calibration source over on the lower right there. Should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdlTv.png) when you have things set right. (But I definitely think you need to send me your unit to my "bad unit graveyard" where it will be well taken care of. :)

Comment: @jonk The display stabilizes (i.e. the trigger level is high enough) at >= 200mV. It definitely didn't do this until recently. I don't mind if you add it to your oscilloscope graveyard, but you'd have to live within the distance I can kick it.

Comment: @par Hehe. Can you get a shot of this ***with*** the trigger line showing up on the screen while you are rotating the dial? And are you saying that the unit worked well up until some moment in time where it started behaving like this? My first thought isn't to imagine some damage or failed part, but instead to imagine that you accidentally changed some saved config, somewhere. I don't have the MSO, only the DS, unfortunately. And I don't have a thought right now that would explain the vertical jitter that seems to appear in the blue trace other than a trigger close to one end or the other.

Comment: @par And that's not even a noisy vertical jitter. It's a distinct set of two bands. If the yellow trace is with the ground and tip of the probe coupled and it is also producing these two isolated and distinct bands, as well, and if we somehow can exclude this as free-running (not sure about that yet, myself) .... I wonder if you may happen to have a 50 Ohm BNC terminator cap? (Youtube video showing something like what I'm thinking about is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GyCAe34N0k).)

Comment: @jonk Well I just did the factory-reset procedure and it is back to reading normally. I guess I'll close this question. I have no idea what setting would cause that vertical bounce though. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @par I was able to reproduce it here. Took some work to find it. I had to screw with the trigger's "when" section and mess with a few other things to get there, though.

Comment: @par Instead of deleting you could post the procedure and select it as an answer.

Comment: What @devnull said.  Then the question/answer pair will be for everybody, not just for you.